# Structure for shop (e-commerce) database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database, e-commerce

I write my project and I will give to user to add his store to my system and then user will can to add shopItem to his store.

My question is:

Maybe already exist shop database for Category-Subcategory.

I mean - When user will add for example boots - he need choose 
Category Clothes -> then choose Subcategory Shoes.

So i need database with all category-subcategory for MS SQL - or other database (maximum I will write script for transfer data to MS SQL)

Thank you.

Regards,
David.

Comment: So @David what is the actual question here.. furthermore you need to read the following link [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) lastly.. this is not a `Code Factory Site` sounds like you better start doing some research on Databases / SQL and start showing some effort on your end.. also please proof read what you write here before posting there are plenty of free online grammar and spell check app on the web what is `Scturucture`

Answer (score 2):

You are talking about a hierarchical relationship.  Typically you would have a Category database which has a primary key (say, CategoryID).  If a subcategory can only belong to single category, then you would have another field in your Category table (maybe called ParentCategoryID).  For root-level categories, this field would be NULL.  For a subcategory, ParentCategoryID would contain the CategoryID of whatever category is the parent (pretty logical).

If a subcategory can exist under multiple categories, then you need a mapping table that contains the CategoryID and ParentCategory ID.

If you need a subcategory also to be allowed to be a root category, then your mapping table has to take this into account (maybe by allowing NULLs in the ParentCategoryID table)

MSDN has a tutorial on hierarchical data structures here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213.aspx